# Programatically setting background of LinearLayout is stretching the image

Tags: android

How would I go about setting the background of a LinearLayout to a specific image (which is acquired from the Internet), without stretching the image?

Basically I have the following piece of code which converts a a Bitmap into a BitmapDrawable, which in turn allows me to programmatically set the background of a LinearLayout:

```
BitmapDrawable myBackground = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap);
myLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(myBackground);
```

The problem is, the image stretches to match the height and width of the LinearLayout; it doesn't center itself horizontally and vertically like it would if I had set the background to be a drawable in the XML layout. How can I achieve this with my bitmap that is retrieved from the Internet?

Comment: Try not to change the background layer, and use it for `ImageView`. How set size of image: `image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 50;`, `image_view.getLayoutParams().width = 50;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use an imageView behind your linearLayout (use another viewGroup like an relativeLayout to achieve that) and set the scaleType of the imageView accordingly... (http://etcodehome.blogspot.co.at/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

Answer (score -1):

It happens because backgroundDrawable have no right to change layout params of the parent layout.

You have 2 options:

1 -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

2 - setSize of LinearLayout with your hands

```
BitmapDrawable myBackground = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap);
LayoutParams lp = myLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = myBitmap.getWidth();
lp.height = myBitmap.getHeight();
myLinearLayout.setlayoutParams(lp)
myLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(myBackground);
```

and you should override onDraw(Canvas c) method of BitmapDrawable, to draw bitmap in center
now it look like : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java#BitmapDrawable.draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29

Comment: The second choice is changing the layout size, you mustn't do this by changing something else i think.